# BPP (complexity)

Tags: computational-complexity, turing-machines, computational-algebra

For any language $L \subseteq \mathbb{B^{*}}$ we define language $2 \cdot L$ as set $\{2 \cdot \overline{a} | \overline{a} \in L\}$, where $2$ in binary form equals $10$,and  $\cdot$ - is multiplication of two binary numbers.

Prove:

if $L \in \mathbf{BPP}$, then $2 \cdot L \in \mathbf{BPP}$.

I know how to show it for not probabilistic Turing machine. Its just simple Turing machine for multiplication of two binary numbers. I dont know how to show it with probability and I stuck here.

Comment: Does $2 \cdot a$ mean that you double the string? Hint: Start with a TM that recognizes $L$, and try to turn it into one that recognizes $2 L$. If you had a TM that recognized words from the English language, and you wanted a machine to recognize words like "dogdog'' or "mathmath", what could you do?

Comment: We really do need a definition of $2\cdot \bar a$. Does $2\cdot\text{dog}$ mean "dogdog" or "ddoogg" or something else? In any case, the comment by @Lorenzo gives a good start for dealing with the case of deterministic computation. To handle the randomizations involved in BPP, it will probably be useful to remember that the error probability of an algorithm can be greatly reduced by repeating the algorithm several times and taking the majority vote of the resulting answers.

Comment: @AndreasBlass 2 thats 10 in binary form

Comment: Unfortunately, being able to convert $2$ to binary form doesn't seem to clarify what $2\cdot\bar a$ means. Lorenzo guessed one meaning ("dogdog"). The usual notion of ordinal multiplication suggests another ("ddoogg"). Your comment suggests a third ("10dog"). But an answer to your question will need a definition, not guesses and suggestions.

Comment: @AndreasBlass $10 \cdot \overline{a}$ - thats just multiplication of two binary numbers. I know how to show algorithm of Turing machine for multiplication without probability. I stuck with probability...

Comment: So $2\cdot\bar a$ is different from all the guesses in earlier comments. It's just appending a zero at the end of $\bar a$.(since that's how multiplication by $2$ works in binary). Fortunately, that makes your problem trivial. The BPP algorithm for testing whether a binary string is in $2\cdot L$ is: First look at the last digit of the input string. If it's $1$, output "no". If it's $0$, delete that last digit and apply the BPP algorithm for $L$ to the string that remains.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks :) now I see it ;)

Comment: According to your explanation, about multiplication by 2 and about regarding binary strings as binary numbers, $2\cdot L$ consists of those strings whose last digit is $0$ and whose other digits constitute a string in $L$. (Equivalently, identifying binary strings with numbers, $2\cdot L$ consists of those even numbers which, when divided by $2$, produce a quotient in $L$.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass But, dont I have to use probability here? BPP is class with probabilistic Turing machine

Comment: Probability gets involved at the last stage of the algorithm I described, "apply the BPP algorithm for $L$ to the string that remains." The error probability for my algorithm applied to a string $2\cdot\bar a$ that ends with $0$ is the same as the error probability of the given BPP algorithm for $L$ applied to $\bar a$. And the error probability for my algorithm appled to a string that ends with $1$ is zero.  (P.S. I trust you're aware that any deterministic algorithm is also a probabilistic algorithm.)